# Why is mud muddy?

Tags: soft-question, water, everyday-life, friction, soft-matter

How to explain properties of mixture of sand with water? Why is it so coherent and slippery at  the same time? Is it due to hydrogen bonds? Why is mud of smaller grains more slippery and incoherent and mud of bigger grains is more coherent and less slippery?

Answer (score 2):

There is a profound difference between sand and mud.

Sand is composed of grains of silicon dioxide, and these grains are relatively large and approximately round but with jagged facets. The grittiness of water/sand mixtures is due to physical interactions between these grains. At low volume fractions sand water dispersions have low viscosity, but at volume fractions of greater than around 0.5 interactions between the grains cause the dispersions to become [dilatant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilatant).

On the other hand mud is composed largely of [clays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_minerals). The word *clay* is a generic term for a large class of aluminosilicates all of which have a layered crystal structure and many of which delaminate in water to form small and very thin platelike crystals. This has two consequences. Firstly a small amount of clay expands to take up a large amount of water, so clay dispersions are typically very viscous. Hence the *gluely* feel of clays. Secondly, under shear the plates tend to align and can slide over each other even at high volume fractions of clay. That is why clay is thick at low shear rates but can be deformed at high stresses - this property is known as [shear thinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_thinning).

Both sand/water dispersions and clays are [non-Newtonian fluids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_Newtonian_fluids), but their behaviour under shear is essentially opposite.

Comment: Can't resist adding that there's a difference between a sand-slide and a mudslide (the latter being a concoction of alcohol and chocolate) :-)